# Why numerical methods diverge from analytical soliton solution of the nonlinear Schrodinger equation after some time $t$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, simulation, soliton-theory

After doing some simulations on soliton solutions of the non-linear Schrodinger equation of the form $$iu_t+u_{xx}+|u|^2u=0$$ whose soliton solution is $$u(x,t)=2 \operatorname{sech} \left( \sqrt{2} (x-2t) \right) \,e^{i(x-2t)},$$ I realized that numerical methods give an accurate solution only for some short time; after some time $t$ numerical solutions start becoming different from the analytical solution above, but it seems like the localized area remains unchanged - it's the surrounding area that seems to change.
Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

The non-linear term mixes the frequency components. In the numerical solution this happens slightly differently than in the exact solution, thus high-frequency components do not sum exactly and some high-frequency oscillation becomes visible.

In
$$
u_t=i(u_xx+|u|^2u)
$$
the time derivative is orthogonal to $u$. Thus
$$
\frac12\partial_t\int |u(x,t)|^2dx=\int Re(\bar u u_t)dx
=...+\int Re(-i|\bar u_x|^2+i|u|^2) =0
$$
or nearly so if the boundary values are small. This relation is better preserved by the solvers, so that the area remains (visibly) constant fora longer time.